# Retrying Azure Service Bus message if the Azure Function fails

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm introducing **Azure Service Bus** and a **Azure Function** in a legacy system where majority of the services are in the on-prem datacenter. The ASB will receive an event called **CC_SUBMITTED**, and the Azure Function called **PaymentService** will be trigged for that event.

The business logic in the **Azure Function** can fail due to data error or a third party service call in the function can return an exception. If the error is in the data, the data will be fixed manually and running the logic again.

Should I send the event **CC_SUBMITTED** back to the ESB from the Azure Function **PaymentService** if there is a failure to reprocess the message? Is there any built-in feature in Azure Service Bus to retry the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any built-in feature in Azure Service Bus to retry the
> message?

Not in Azure Service Bus as such but this is handled through Functions. If a Function fails with an error, the message is sent back to the Service Bus and then will be retried after some time. The process will be repeated until either the Function executes successfully or the message is dead lettered.

> Should I send the event CC_SUBMITTED back to the ESB from the Azure
> Function PaymentService if there is a failure to reprocess the
> message?

Normally no, but in your scenario I would say yes. The reason I say yes is because based on the information you provided in the post, usually the process will fail because of issues with the data and requires some manual correction of the data. Thus, there is no point in keep on retrying the operation if we know the it will only succeed once the data is corrected.

However if the operation is failing because of transient errors, then the in-built retry mechanism in the Function should be able to handle that.

Comment: What is your suggestion on how to initiate the retry of the same message after a day when the data is fixed? Should I write a **Azure Function** that runs every day and pick up the failed messages and send them to the queue again?

Comment: You can certainly do that. Let the message get dead-lettered and then run a separate Azure Function that runs every day (or some other frequency) to move the message from dead-letter sub-queue to the main queue so that it can be picked by your main Function.